# Foxpro DB to Database.com DB script

Tags: database, foxpro

Extreemly limited coding experience here. But I believe what I'm looking to accomplish should be very simple. However I've no idea how to begin.

I have a desktop retail-software program that sends its data to a remote Foxpro database every night at 7PM (user button click 'send data'). I believe it has 5 tables.

I want to develop a script that sends the data written in the remote Foxpro DB to database.com, every night at 12midnight.

It could either completely overwrite the tables or send only the updated data.

Is this as simple as I think? Where/how should I begin?

Thank you - Brent

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to go to database.com and start reading about their API. I would probably choose synchronous CRUD updates using JSON after a 10 second look.

Assuming you picked that option, you need to then develop something that could handle sending the DBF data up to database.com via their API.

With the information given, if it were me, I would use a C# console application, using ODBC or OLE DB to connect yo your FoxPro tables, probably [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) to handle serialising it to JSON and the built-in .NET HTTP functionality to handle sending it database.com. You could then run this EXE using the Windows scheduler.

However you say 'a remote FoxPro database'. How remote? Do you have access to it?

Comment: Remote geographically - its in Houston, I'm in Seattle. Having issues with the helpfulness of the db administrator. I just need to arm myself with information about the simplicity of my request.

Comment: Well, what I was trying to get at is that it's a fairly common but non-trivial task, especially since you have limited coding experience.